# Why GPU-Util is zero with high GPU memory-usage during deep model inference?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, gpu

### Background

I am currently working on a job which requires deep learning model **inference** (or **prediction**) instead of **training** task. I would like to accelerate the **inference** process on GPU.

### Problem

I am using **keras** module in tensorflow to load a well-trained DNN model for MNIST digit classification task. Basically, what I need is: input a batch of images into the DNN model, and the model outputs a corresponding batch of scores. Since I need to repeat such process numerous amount of times, I would like to utilize GPU accleration. So I specified in the code with

```py
with tf.device('/gpu:1'):
```

,which, ideally, should use the second GPU.

However, when I run my python program, I found it very very slow.
My CPU information gives:
[CPU info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WvynB.png)
where the **python3** process should be my python program.

My GPU information gives:
[GPU info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Tprz.png)
and can be concluded as

- 2nd GPU (GPU 1) has its memory all occupied
- 2nd GPU has no GPU-Util
- no process on GPU is running in my container

From the above information, I suspect that my program is completely running on CPU.

### Setting

The basic hardware & software setting of my server is listed as following:

1. OS:

```
Linux e46efe9289d3 5.4.0-72-generic #80~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 12 23:26:25 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

2. CPU:

```
128  AMD Ryzen Threadripper 3990X 64-Core Processor
```

3. GPU:

```
GPU 0: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 (UUID: )
GPU 1: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 (UUID: )
GPU 2: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 (UUID: )
GPU 3: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 3090 (UUID: )
```

4. CUDA:

```sh
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2021 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Sun_Aug_15_21:14:11_PDT_2021
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.4, V11.4.120
Build cuda_11.4.r11.4/compiler.30300941_0
```

5. CUDNN:

```py
#define CUDNN_MAJOR 8
#define CUDNN_MINOR 2
#define CUDNN_PATCHLEVEL 4
```

6. tensorflow (GPU version):

```py
>>> tf.__version__
'2.5.0'
```

### Help

Can you help me to deploy the DNN inference task on GPU?

Comment: What is "very very slow" exactly, as in numbers? Also you don't need 4 GPUs to train or do inference on a MNIST model, as they are very small models.

Comment: And you have the wrong conclusions, three GPUs are being used, so you cannot conclude that your code is running on CPU.

Comment: 1. "very very slow" means it takes around 30s for 100 times of inference, with batch size = 2; 2. since I am in a container, there are other users running programs on the rest of the GPUs, and I cannot see their processes by `nvidia-smi` command, so I believe I have the correct conclusion

Comment: The tensorflow logs actually tell you if the GPU was detected and if its being used, you cannot infer if GPU is being used by looking at utilization. Also to increase performance, increase the batch size, a batch size of 2 is ridiculously low, try at least 128 or even higher up to 1024, GPUs are massively parallel processors so they need a good amount of parallelism.

Comment: To be more detailed about utilization, GPUs are massive processors, if you have a tiny MNIST model, with a small batch size, it is easy to get utilizations between 0.0 and 1.0, and if utilization is less than 1.0 %, it will be reported as zero, so you cannot use utilization to determine if GPU is being used or not.

Comment: **1**.Thanks for your suggestion, I tried `tf.debugging.set_log_device_placement(True)` and found that, according to the log, the operations in my program are switching between CPU:0 and GPU:1 **2**. my task is against such large batch size, so maybe running on CPU is enough? **3**.I tried to limit the operations on only CPU, but no significant efficiency improvement. I found the bottleneck for each epoch is an operation called `DeleteIterator` since the log information always stuck there for around 5-10s. Any idea to handle this?

Comment: Some operations are always handled by the CPU, you cannot have code that only runs in the GPU, for example loading data into RAM requires both CPU and GPU. This sounds like you are bottlenecked by data loading, but not sure. You are not going to get good performance with a lot batch size, both on CPU and GPU. What I meant by tensorflow logs is what is printed in the terminal when training or doing inference.

Comment: I increased batch size to 512 and used tensorflow operations instead of numpy, it really goes much faster. Besides, I found gpu util goes to 7%, but still no process is detected by `nvidia-smi`